# Draft.js text block conversion into HTML on Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I need help with implementation. There is the following structure:

```
{
    "data": {},
    "depth": 0,
    "entityRanges": [],
    "inlineStyleRanges": [
        {
            "length": 4,
            "offset": 4,
            "style": "BOLD"
        },
        {
            "length": 4,
            "offset": 20,
            "style": "BOLD"
        },
        {
            "length": 8,
            "offset": 8,
            "style": "ITALIC"
        },
        {
            "length": 12,
            "offset": 12,
            "style": "STRIKE"
        }
    ],
    "text": "testtesttesttesttesttest",
    "type": "unstyled",
    "key": "5kucc"
}
```

There's a task to convert a block from draft.js to Python, but I'm having trouble doing it.

I tried to do it this way:

```
from operator import itemgetter
tags = {
    "STRIKE": {
        "in": "<strike>",
        "out": "</strike>"
    },
    "BOLD": {
        "in": "<b>",
        "out": "</b>"
    },
    "ITALIC": {
        "in": "<i>",
        "out": "</i>"
    },
}

def proceedText(block):
  inlineStyleRanges = block['inlineStyleRanges']
  entityRanges = block['entityRanges']
  text = block['text']
  result = ""
  inlineStyleRanges = sorted(inlineStyleRanges, key=itemgetter('offset')) 
  entityRanges = sorted(entityRanges, key=itemgetter('offset')) 
  lenText = len (text)
    for i in range(1, lenText + 1):
      pos = i - 1
      for j in inlineStyleRanges:
        if (pos == j['offset']):
          result += tags[j['style']]['in']
          result += text[pos]
        elif (pos == j['offset'] + j['length']):
          result += tags[j['style']]['out']
        elif (pos > j['offset'] and pos < j['offset'] + j['length']):
          result += text[pos]

  print(result)
```

It is only at this point that the code behavior is strange enough to at least assign styles to the text, not to mention the fact that it was done without using libraries.
Expected result: `test<b>test</b><i>test</i><strike><i>test</i><b>test</b>test</strike>`
At the same time we need help to implement here also entityRanges with LINK format.
Actual result: `<b>test</b><i>testt<strike>teesstt</i>testt<b>teesstt`
This code tries to go through all the inlineStyleRange dictionaries and attribute tags.
The code goes through all the offsets and if the position matches it puts either an opening or closing HTML tag. There is no HTML body, as I need it for integration with separate editors. For personal reasons I don't intend to use draft.js. If anyone has experience with lxml, you can adapt the code to it. I haven't found any other similar solutions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Where are `itemgetter` and `tags` variables defined?

Comment: I forgot, now I added it.

Comment: Why do you expect double italic tag: `<i>test</i><strike><i>test</i>`, although in `inlineStyleRanges` it occurs only once.

Comment: One tag "i" doesn't have a tag "strike", and since the following is an example of strikethrough text, so the tag "i" is duplicated again, since it is already followed by the tag "b".

Comment: `tag "i" is duplicated again, since it is already followed by the tag "b"` —  in this case complication of the script increases significantly